# Как решить проблему с ie7,8,9. Что заработало overflow:hidden. Через js прописал, так же не помогло

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, javascript

Как решить проблему, надо скрыть блоки, а они светятся.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы решить эту проблему, нужно к родительскому элементу применить position: relative;
Т.е.:
`<div style="position: relative"> 
     <div style="overflow:hidden"> 
     ТЕКСТ
     </div> 
</div>`

Comment: да, релатив был у родительского дива, вот посмотри mackay.kz/sites/3/